# Filter data in between forward and backslash

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am using Pig Latin to filter data records and the below mentioned line is the records where I am stuck.
The input line:
/ACTRC5/TXN08/SCR301\/SEQ/TEX021\@

The output that I am expecting is:
ACTRC5,TXN08,SCR301,SEQ,TEX021

The number of backslashes can be of any number of times and the input records can be quite long. I am not sure what approach I should use to get the output.

Any help/suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem:

The file **problem.txt** contains the following data with any sequence of \ or special characters:

Sample data -- **//ACTRC5//TXN08/SCR301/SEQ//TEX021\@**

The first step is to simple load the data:

```
A = LOAD 'problem.txt' as line;

--The next two steps use the String Replace function to clean the data as per your needs:

B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(line,'([^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+)',',') AS (data:chararray);

C = FOREACH B GENERATE REPLACE(data,'(^,|,$)','');

DUMP C;
```

Output: **ACTRC5,TXN08,SCR301,SEQ,TEX021**

Here I am using two stages to clean the data, I will try posting the single step solution later. This should help for now.